# How can I save a pdf with wicked-pdf and inspect it as an html

Tags: wicked-pdf

I am creating a pdf file and saving it.

```
 pdf=WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  html,
  header: {content: html_header},
  footer: {content: html_footer},
  page_height: '11in',
  page_width: '8.5in',
  show_as_html: true
)

save_path = Rails.root.join('example.pdf')
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end
return
```

Is it possible to open that with chrome as an html and inspect the css ?

Comment: Why do you think you can inspect a PDF as HTML at all?

Comment: Because wicked pdf supports a debug mode in which you can preview it as an html.

Comment: So, that's covered in the docs. https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#debugging  What's not working?

Comment: It's partially covered, but doesn't have a clear example.

Comment: Have you tried it?  It specifically says to call the endpoint with a ?debug querystring parameter in order to see the HTML.

Comment: I have tried yes, and is not working.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your `show_as_html: true` to `show_as_html: params.key?('debug')`

After that, try to visit the url of pdf adding a `?debug` at the end.

For example: http://localhost:3000/controller/file.pdf?debug

Now you can inspect the HTML as usual.